# constantly change color of sprite in sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I would like to make my sprite smoothly change its color in a loop. However, everything that I could find used UIKit. Is there any way to do this without using UI kit. This is what I would like to do but in UIKit:

```
 let red   = Float((arc4random() % 256)) / 255.0
    let green = Float((arc4random() % 256)) / 255.0
    let blue  = Float((arc4random() % 256)) / 255.0
    let alpha = Float(1.0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options:[.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }, completion:nil)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Describe everything a bit more...And show what you have tried so far...

Comment: @Whirlwind sorry I forgot to say that I would like everything change smoothly. I will make some code for what it would be like in UIKit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use something like this to change the background. You can probably move the getRandomColor into UIColor as an extension so you can use it across your project.

```
override func sceneDidLoad() {

    func getRandomColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor.init(red: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max),
                            green: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max),
                            blue: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max),
                            alpha: 1)
    }

    if let frame = self.scene?.frame {
        let background = SKSpriteNode(color: .blue,
                                      size: CGSize(width: frame.width, 
                                                   height: frame.height))

        background.run(SKAction.repeatForever(
            SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.run {
                    background.run(SKAction.colorize(with: getRandomColor(),
                                                     colorBlendFactor: 1,
                                                     duration: 1))
                },
                SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)])
        ))

        self.addChild(background)
    }

}
```

Comment: rather than statically changing I would like it smoothly change

Comment: I added roughly what I would like in UIkit up above

Comment: Are you trying to animate a background changing color? Or is it a circle?

Comment: oh oops I meant animate in a loop not a circle sorry

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of a fading background